Why does the s2 signal have the opposite value as the s3 signal after the nanosecond 20?
I have this code in VHDL:
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity crono is
end entity crono;

architecture crono of crono is
    signal x1, x2, x3, s1, s2, s3, s4: std_logic;
begin
    x1 <= '1',
          '0' after 15 ns,
          '1' after 20 ns,
          '0' after 35 ns,
          '1' after 50 ns;
    x2 <= '0',
          '1' after 25 ns,
          '0' after 30 ns;
    x3 <= '0',
          '1' after 10 ns,
          '0' after 20 ns;
    s1 <= x1 after 5 ns;
    Proc1: process (x1, x2, x3)
        variable v1: std_logic;
    begin
        s2 <= x1 xor x2;
        v1 := x1 xor x2;
        s3 <= s2;
        s4 <= v1;
    end process;
end architecture crono;

And it generates this waves:

Dont know why s2 and s3 signals are opposite when they should be the same after the 20 nanosecond mark, I really have no clue.
Edit: I just noticed my misunderstanding, the signal doesnt update until the end of the process block. This means that the signal "s3" doesn't take the new "s2" value.

Your comment here isn't searchable, you can edit your question to add more detail. Note s2 isn't in the process sensitivity list. Your waveform could display x1, x2, and x3 as well. Something to show simulation time would be useful as well.

Adding s2 to sensitivity list of Proc1 makes s2=s3=s4

"Dont know why s2 and s3 signals are opposite when they should be the same after the 20 nanosecond mark" -> s2 and s3 are the same at time 0, since you have in your code x1 initialized to 1 and x1 is Proc1 sensitivity list.

Yeah, my purpose isn't to edit the code, just wanted to know the reason of that situation.
